# How to pass and receive data between screens in compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm utilizing the NavHostController for navigation and wish to send custom models between screens.
SafeArgs only works with fragments/views, so passing a bundle isn't an option. The only thing I see in the documentation is Type-Safe transmission, which appears to be limited to simple types such as Int, Float, and Strings:

```
fun NavController.navigateToConversation(conversationId: String) {
    this.navigate("conversation/$conversationId")
}
```

However, I have a need to transmit more complex data.
How can I effectively achieve bidirectional communication for such data between screens with compose?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/raamcosta/compose-destinations for this.

Comment: Can't believe there isnt a built-in way to transmit models

Comment: Can you consider a different approach for this? Sending listeners does not seem like a good idea, and it won't be supported even by the library linked above, since it would serialize data and then recreate it on destination (meaning it would be a different listener then). You could move the code needed to send data between the screens to a separate class that could be a singleton or managed some other way.

Comment: Interesting approach, ill think about it. But what about sending whole models with data forwards and backwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the navigation library for compose falls a bit short in that department.

On the other hand, passing complex data from one screen to another isn't that ideal anyways. Decoupling them makes it easier to modularize your project into independent feature modules. The way to go would be to share just IDs of entities that each screen have to lookup themselves. Alternatively, you could store the data in shared viewmodels.

That said, there are some third party libraries out there that try to fill in the gaps. I personally found [Compose Destinations](https://composedestinations.rafaelcosta.xyz/) to be mature and easy to use.

Comment: Ill try storing data in sharedviewmodels and will definitely use the library.